# How to make the hint text of TextInputLayout vertically center?

Tags: material-components

Our design team follow the iOS catalog app , the hint text of TextInputLayout is vertically center, but when I try Android it is not. I don't seem to find an option to make it. So why they are different ? Or there's some way to make it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug with the implementation of `TextInputLayout` in the material design library. We have fixed this internally and will be releasing the updated component soon.

As a work around you may be able to set the padding on the child `TextInputEditText` to adjust it so it is centered.

Comment: This still doesn't appear to be fixed. Was the fix released or are we still waiting on it?

Comment: The fix hasn't been in the release yet. It should be in the next release.

Comment: Hi, @CameronKetcham, is the fix in the release yet? Doesn't seem to be fixed on 1.1.0-alpha01 on my end.