# Center text vertically inside Android material TextInputLayout when it has fixed height in DP

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I have a TextInputLayout which I want to have its height defined explicitly in `DP`.

When I tried that, the text was not aligned inside TextInputLayout vertically in center. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50487871/1080355) already asked something like this but it did not receive enough attention and did not have updated answers yet and the suggested solution is not working fine.

As you might see it will be something like this:

[image]

Here is my layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/TextInputLayoutPassword"
            style="@style/CustomInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewMainTitle"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
            android:textColorHint="@color/text_input_layout_stroke_color"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/text_input_layout_hint_color"
            android:hint="@string/userPassword"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="2dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="18dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="18dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="18dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="18dp">
        <!--this is the actual edit text which takes the input-->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextPassword"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"

                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to limit the size of your TextInput component like that?  This will make it even harder to read for Users who use a bigger font size.

Comment: @IvánGarzaBermea I have a limited set of devices for running my application. So the settings are almost in a fixed range but I want to have an acceptable view for that limited set of devices which seems to be a bit hard to be managed by `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: Is this still an issue @VSB?

Comment: @IvánGarzaBermea yes. This `TextInputEditText` View is so tricky and hard to be controlled comparing stuff like `EditText`

Comment: @IvánGarzaBermea the issue  to keep height of inputlayout and edittext in harmony with each other still persists when we want to specify an specific height